# Changing multiple image background on scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i hope some one will help me solve this, i'm so bad at javascript and not so good at html n css either.

i want to change image background on scroll with fade effect, I've create fiddle for this.

```js
 var $nav = $('nav');
 var winh = window.innerHeight;
 var scrollPos = 0;
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {

   scrollPos = Number($(window).scrollTop().toFixed(1));
   page = Math.floor(Number(scrollPos / winh) + 1); 
   if (page == 1) {
     $('.test1').addClass('active');
     $('.test2').removeClass('active');
     $('.test3').removeClass('active');
   } else if (page == 2) {
     $('.test1').removeClass('active');
     $('.test2').addClass('active');
     $('.test3').removeClass('active');
   } else if (page == 3) {
     $('.test1').removeClass('active');
     $('.test2').removeClass('active');
     $('.test3').addClass('active');
   } else {
     $('.test1').removeClass('active');
     $('.test2').removeClass('active');
     $('.test3').removeClass('active');
   }
   $nav.html("Page# " + page + " window position: " + scrollPos);

 });
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.media {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s 1s;
}

.media.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s 0s;
}

.media .image {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.media .caption {
  margin-top: 50vh;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav></nav>
<figure class="media test1" data-media-action="modal">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/05/31/world/australia/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-08UQ/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-08UQ-superJumbo.jpg" />
  </div>
  <figcaption class="caption" itemprop="caption description">
    <div class="caption-text">

      Harvesting kangaroos for meat at Plumbago Station, South Australia.

    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="media test2" data-media-action="modal">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/05/31/world/australia/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-TYTD/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-TYTD-superJumbo.jpg" />
  </div>
  <figcaption class="caption" itemprop="caption description">

    <div class="caption-text">

      Abandoned cars littered an opal mining site in Coober Pedy.

    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="media test3" data-media-action="modal">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/05/31/world/australia/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-EE5O/outback-photo-essay-ss-slide-EE5O-superJumbo.jpg" />
  </div>
  <figcaption class="caption" itemprop="caption description">
    <div class="caption-text">
      FERAL DOGS THAT WERE KILLED BY RANCHERS SEEKING TO PROTECT LIVESTOCK IN TAMBO, QUEENSLAND.
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

here's the problem:

1. i think my code is not efficient and there's gonna be a problem if i have 20 images or more? pls advice for more efficient code.
2. image doesn't show when page load you need to scroll first. how can i make the image load everytime you refresh the page ?
3. why the last image is not the same height with the first and other image ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) yes the code is not efficient instead of using if else you can write a loop for displaying images!! You can store images in a database and retrieve that using queries. You can use a simple SQL database and any scripting language for fetching the data I would suggest PHP

2)soltion for your second question will be by using jquery's load() method instead of using on() method

3) I cannot see the output in fiddle please share the screenshot

Comment: 1. can you give me some example code for that ? i don't know anything about SQL  man, is there another way ?

Comment: u can try this for easy implementation https://github.com/HoffiPL/JQuery-Background-Image-Scroll

Comment: thanks, i think i just go with this https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax, because its responsive too and trying too add fade effect if possible.

Comment: welcome!! u can green tick a answer if it solved your problem :)